# How to execute a pre-trigger in DocumentDB from a JS code or Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a stored procedure in Azure DocumentDB which insert documents in bulk.
How do I execute a trigger in the SP ?

Stored Procedure:

```
function InsertBulk(obj) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

var count = 0;

if (!obj) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

var docsLength = obj.docs.length;
if (docsLength == 0) {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
}

tryCreate(obj.docs[count], callback);
function tryCreate(doc, callback) {
    var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, callback);

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
}

function callback(err, doc, options) {
    if (err) throw err;

    count++;

    if (count >= docsLength) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    } else {
        tryCreate(obj.docs[count], callback);
    }
}}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a good reference for the JS SDK to DocumentDB.

Comment: No, You can't Call Trigger Manually.Triggers are event based statements so they cannot be called explicitly by user in any means. It is automatically executed when we insert,update or delete a table row

Comment: @guyAssaf, references I use most often:

* [Server-side API Docs](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/)


* [Client-side API Docs for node.js](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/)

* [HTTP status codes for Documentdb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783364.aspx)

* [JavaScript language integrated queries (server-side)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#javascript-language-integrated-query-api)

* [SQL Cheat Sheet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, @Dev 's answer is incorrect in saying that triggers in DocumentDB fire implicitly. In every SQL implementation they do but not in DocumentDB. Triggers must be specified explicitly in DocumentDB however they are not permitted to be specified from a sproc. Triggers are only supported in the client-side libraries and even then you have to explicitly specify them for each operation where you want them to trigger.

On the bright side, you can move your trigger logic into your sproc.

Answer (score -2):

you can't call trigger from the stored procedure.

Trigger implicitly fires when you perform any manipulation on the table(like Insert,Update,Delete).

Suppose you have written a procedure for updating the record of the Table. When your procedure will execute,Your created trigger will also fire because it automatically fires when any operation performed on the table.

Good luck & hope this helps.

Comment: To avoid confusion: Remember that there are no *tables*, no *records*. There are *collections* and *documents*.

Comment: A trick can be done here is to add a flag. If new document added flag=1 & immediately add a condition i.e if flag==1 then execute another StoredProcedure which might act as a Trigger for the same & add the logic out there. This should work for sure. Good Luck

Comment: Triggers do not implicitly fire in DocumentDB... a huge deviation from the SQL mental model and making them almost useless, IMHO.

Comment: You wrote, "Trigger implicitly fires when you perform any manipulation". That's what I'm correcting.